# Cannot login to an environment using apictl tool

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using APIM version 3.0.0, apictl version 3.0.1 and I have APIM up and running on windows. I also created an environment named dev.
However, when I try to login to the dev environment using the below command, an error occurs.

Command: apictl login dev -u admin -p admin -k

Error: [Warning: Using --password in CLI is not secure. Use --password-stdin
apictl: Error in connecting. Reason: Post https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp: Auto redirect is disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccdfg.png)

PS: I also set up the environment variables using the main_config.yaml, as below.
[NAME                API MANAGER ENDPOINT     REGISTRATION ENDPOINT             TOKEN ENDPOINT
dev                 https://localhost:9443   https://localhost:9443/register   https://localhost:8243/token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqjzJ.png)

Any suggestive approach to solve this issue is much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have you added the environment configurations correctly as stated in https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.0.0/learn/api-controller/getting-started-with-wso2-api-controller/?

Comment: @npamudika Yes. I added the environment variables in the main_config.yaml as below.                          config:
  export_directory: /home/wso2user/.wso2apictl/exported
  https_request_timeout: 10000
  kubernetes_mode: false
  token_type: JWT
environments:
  dev:
    admin: https://localhost:9443/admin
    publisher: https://localhost:9443/publisher
    apim: https://localhost:9443
    devportal: https://localhost:9443/devportal
    registration: https://localhost:9443/register
    token: https://localhost:8243/token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have used the endpoints names and values as in APICTL 3.1.0. Please note that, in APICTL 3.1.0, the endpoint names and values have been modified. Can you please try adding like below to be matched for APICTL 3.0.1 version?

```
apictl add-env -e production --registration https://localhost:9444/client-registration/v0.15/register --apim https://localhost:9444 --token https://localhost:8244/token --admin https://localhost:9444/api/am/admin/v0.15 --api_list https://localhost:9444/api/am/publisher/v0.15/apis --app_list https://localhost:9444/api/am/store/v0.15/applications
```

Comment: Refer https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.0.0/learn/api-controller/getting-started-with-wso2-api-controller/#add-an-environment for more detals